Open devtools when pinned icon is clicked?
I'm making a Chrome extension which has a devtools panel. Is it possible to open this panel when the pinned icon is clicked?
I can listen for the click even in a background script but Im not sure if it's possible to open the panel?
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
  if (tab.id) {
    //
  }
});


There's no such API.
